# Setting up Varnish Apache2 HTTP & HTTPS Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, varnish

I have Apache2 with several sites on HTTPS (443, Let's encrypte) and HTTP (80), multiple CMS on Ubuntu 16.04, CPUx16, mem=48G. One of HTTPS (Wordpress) is overloaded - a nonprofit site that shows profiles of orphans with photos/videos and receives donations (up to 10k visitors per day). How do i set up Varnish for cache to memory photos/videos requests to reduce disk load?

Here Apache2 `ports.conf`:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

I would be much appreciated for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Apache port configuration

Adjust the `ports.conf` and turn `Listen 80` into `Listen 8080`.

In your *vhosts*, you'll have to turn `<VirtualHost *:80>` into `<VirtualHost *:8080>` as well.

Then you run `sudo systemctl restart apache2` to make sure these changes take effect.

### Varnish setup

Please run `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish` to edit the runtime settings of Varnish.

Please make sure Varnish is running on *port 80* for regular HTTP and *port 8443* for [PROXY protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt).

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -a :8443,PROXY -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,20G
```

### VCL setup

Please create `/etc/varnish/letsencrypt.vcl` and add the following code:

```
vcl 4.0;

backend certbot {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8081";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/") {
        set req.backend_hint = certbot;
        return(pipe);
    }
}

sub vcl_pipe {
    if (req.backend_hint == certbot) {
        set req.http.Connection = "close";
        return(pipe);
    }
}
```

Please include this file directly after `vcl 4.0;` in your regular `/etc/varnish/default.vcl`. Here's an example:

```
vcl 4.0;
include "/etc/varnish/letsencrypt.vcl";

backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

As you see, the backend in `default.vcl` points to *port 8080*, which is Apache.

Please restart Varnish to make sure these VCL settings are active.

### Hitch for TLS termination

[Hitch](http://hitch-tls.org/) is a TLS proxy developed by *Varnish Software*. It's powerful, lightweight and configurable.

Please run the following command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install -y hitch
sudo systemctl enable hitch
```

Then create `/etc/hitch/hitch.conf` and add the following:

```
frontend = "[*]:443"
backend = "[localhost]:8443"
write-proxy-v2 = on
pem-file = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/hitch-bundle.pem"
ciphers = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"
tls = on
ssl = off
prefer-server-ciphers = false
```

### Prepare Hitch for LetsEncrypt

Please create `/usr/local/bin/hitch-deploy-hook` and put the following content in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Full path to pre-generated Diffie Hellman Parameters file
dhparams=/etc/hitch/dhparams.pem

if [[ "${RENEWED_LINEAGE}" == "" ]]; then
    echo "Error: missing RENEWED_LINEAGE env variable." >&2
    exit 1
fi

umask 077
cat ${RENEWED_LINEAGE}/privkey.pem \
${RENEWED_LINEAGE}/fullchain.pem \
${dhparams} > ${RENEWED_LINEAGE}/hitch-bundle.pem
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/hitch-deploy-hook
openssl dhparam 2048 | sudo tee /etc/hitch/dhparams.pem
```

### Running Cerbot

Make sure the *LetsEncrypt* cerbot is installed, by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y certbot
```

Then run the following command to install the certificates:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http \
--http-01-port 8081 -d yourdomain.com \
--deploy-hook="/usr/local/bin/hitch-deploy-hook"
```

After the validation, the certificate will be available at `/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourdomain.com/hitch-bundle.pem`, which *Hitch* will use.

Please run `sudo systemctl restart hitch` to enable Hitch.

*LetsEncrypt* renewals can also be done using this binary. When renewing, please make sure you reload Hitch as a *post renewal hook*:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http \
--http-01-port 8081 -d yourdomain.com \
--deploy-hook="/usr/local/bin/hitch-deploy-hook" \
--post-hook="systemctl reload hitch"
```

> I use `yourdomain.com` as the domain in my examples. Please replace it with the actual value.

Comment: Site do not start after renewing. All https do not work: "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: When run 'openssl dhparam 2048 | sudo tee /etc/hitch/dhparams.pem' there was warning msg: _unable to write 'random state'_. However process ended well with BEGIN/END DH PARAMETERS and some coded text between.

Comment: All commands from your instruction run successfully. Letsencript renewed successfully twice (every time i chose "Renew & replace the cert"). But after renew all sites didnt load properly. Now I've switched to old configuration and pem-keys

Comment: That's a tough one to debug for me. But the fact that you're getting *"The page isn't redirecting properly"*, means that TLS termination was successful. One thing that could cause problems is the fact that *PROXY protocol* isn't properly on Varnish.

I'm going to need some more information, and a better visualization of the issue before being able to give you advice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the walkthru, but I'd like to ask one more question - how do you set up MULTIPLE domains? Virtualhosts on apache (i have that), how to do the PEM file for Hitch? Is it simply concat of all the ssl files into one? or else?

Comment: I would have a `.pem` file per virtualhost and use the `pem-dir` syntax in Hitch to load multiple certificates at once. The built-in SNI feature will match the right hostname to the right certificate. See https://github.com/varnish/hitch/blob/master/hitch.conf.man.rst#pem-dir--string. You can also use `pem-dir-glob` to apply a glob pattern to only allow `.pem` files to be loaded from that directory. See https://github.com/varnish/hitch/blob/master/hitch.conf.man.rst#pem-dir-glob--string